# Automatic Assembley x86 Obfuscation Tool

Tags: assembly, obfuscation

I have some Assembler code for an application, does anyone know of a tool that can automatically obfuscate the code?

Thanks.

Comment: Assembly is pretty much self-obfuscating, I would have thought.

Comment: Assembly compiles directly into machine code. As long as you don't include symbols (which include the labels defined in your source code), there is nothing to obfuscate. You can't write assembly and prevent someone who has access to it from seeing your exact code in assembly.

Comment: In order to obfuscate assembler, one can transform simple operations to "rube-goldberg" machines -- basically that's what every beginner does...

Comment: That exists, it's used by some viruses.

Comment: @Clafou Introduce some additional moves to registers, replace arithmetic instructions by the negated inverse instructions, use of logical instructions while calculating addresses.... I could think of many more ideas. The point is that while it is impossible to hide the machine code, you can make it hard to comprehend, which may be sufficient.

Comment: Aki, harold, hirschhornsalz, fair enough. I just wanted to point out that compile-time obfuscation isn't possible there (in contrast with obfuscation tools for Java or .NET for example), so you'd have to modify the source code in order to make it hard to understand, which probably defeats the purpose as if you write assembly it's typically to do things efficiently.

Comment: @Clafou it's not actually illegal for an assembler to output something silly as long as the semantics are preserved though - only crazy. Then the assembler would have to know the semantics of instructions, instead of just how to encode them. But it could be done..